# Sorting balls into boxes with conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I need help getting at general formulas that can be used with different numbers, so please explain how you arrived at your answer and provide an approach that I can use with different values.

1. How many ways can 50 balls be sorted into 10 boxes with 5 balls per box,
   a. when boxes are not labeled, but balls are, and
   b. when neither boxes or balls are labeled?
2. If there are 4 yellow balls and 46 blue balls, how many ways can balls be sorted into 10 boxes with 5 balls per box such that there are:
   a. 4 boxes with a yellow ball,
   b. 3 boxes with at least one yellow ball,
   c. 2 boxes with at least one yellow ball,
   d. 1 box with all 4 yellow balls?
   For this set of questions, boxes are not labeled and individual balls are not labeled except by color.
3. How would the answers to questions 1 and 2 change if the boxes could contain any non-zero number of balls?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a more positive response if you show that you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself.  How far have you gotten?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Shortcut/hint: google "Stirling numbers" (with or without quotes).